# how to write web based application to write to hadoop table

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hue

I need to design a page or web based app where users :
- can login
- view a predefined table from hdfs 
- write to the same table

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40300222/best-practice-to-launch-spark-applications-via-web-application/40301106#40301106

Comment: Thanks !! I am working to understand this better.