# Can MLLib classifiers be trained and used without a Spark installation?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I want to use some of the classifiers provided by MLLib (random forests, etc) but I want to use them without connecting to a Spark cluster.

If I need to somehow run some Spark stuff in-process so that I have a Spark context to use, that's fine. But I haven't been able to find any information or an example for such a use case.

So my two questions are:

- Is there a way to use the MLLib classifiers without a Spark context at all?
- Otherwise, can I use them by starting a Spark context in-process, without needing any kind of actual Spark installation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`org.apache.spark.mllib` models:

- Cannot be trained without Spark cluster.
- Usually can be used for predictions without cluster, with exception to distributed models like ALS.

`org.apache.spark.ml` models:

- Require Spark cluster for training.
- Require Spark cluster for predictions although it might change in the future (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10413)

There is a number of third party tools which are designed to export Spark `ml` models to the form which can be used in Spark agnostic environment (`jpmml-spark` and `modeldb` to enumerate a few, without special preference).

Spark `mllib` models have limited PMML support as well.

Commercial vendors usually provide their own tools for productionizing Spark models.

You can of course use `local` "cluster", but it is probably still a bit to heavy for most of possible applications. Starting a full context take at least a few seconds, and has significant memory footprint.

Also:

- [Best Practice to launch Spark Applications via Web Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40300222/8115764)
- [How to serve a Spark MLlib model?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40533582/8115764)