# Set spark.driver.memory for Spark running inside a web application

Tags: scala, apache-spark, memory

I have a REST API in Scala Spray that triggers Spark jobs like the following:

```
path("vectorize") {
        get {
          parameter('apiKey.as[String]) { (apiKey) =>
            if (apiKey == API_KEY) {
              MoviesVectorizer.calculate() // Spark Job run in a Thread (returns Future)
              complete("Ok")
            } else {
              complete("Wrong API KEY")
            }

          }
        }
      }
```

I'm trying to find the way to specify Spark driver memory for the jobs. As I found, configuring driver.memory from within the application code doesn't effect anything.

The whole web application along with the Spark is packaged in a fat Jar.
I run it by running

```
java -jar app.jar
```

Thus, as I understand, spark-submit is not relevant here (or is it?). So, I can not specify --driver-memory option when running the app.

Is there any way to set the driver memory for Spark within the web app?

Here's my current Spark configuration:

```
val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
                        .appName("Recommender")
                        .master("local[*]")
                        .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", uri)
                        .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", uri)
                        .config("spark.mongodb.keep_alive_ms", "100000")
                        .getOrCreate()

spark.conf.set("spark.executor.memory", "10g")
val sc = spark.sparkContext
sc.setCheckpointDir("/tmp/checkpoint/")
val sqlContext = spark.sqlContext
```

As it is said in the documentation, Spark UI Environment tab shows only variables that are effected by the configuration. Everything I set is there - apart from spark.executor.memory.

Comment: Thanks, I guess title should be _Set spark.executor.memory for Spark running inside a web application_, right?

Comment: Yeah, Title is set properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you use `local` mode. In `local` mode there is no real executor - all Spark components run in a single JVM, with single heap configuration, so executor specific configuration doesn't matter.

`spark.executor` options are applicable only when applications is submitted to a cluster.

Also, Spark supports only a single application per JVM instance. This means that all core Spark properties, will be applied only when `SparkContext` is initialized, and persist as long as context (not `SparkSession`) is kept alive. Since `SparkSession` initializes `SparkContext`, no additional "core" settings will can applied after `getOrCreate`.

This means that all "core" options should be provided using `config` method of the `SparkSession.builder`.

If you're looking for alternatives to embedding you check an [exemplary answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40301106/9613318) to [Best Practice to launch Spark Applications via Web Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40300222/9613318) by [T. Gawęda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5811800/t-gaw%c4%99da).

---

**Note**: Officially Spark doesn't support applications running outside `spark-submit` and there are some elusive bugs related to that.

Comment: Thank you. Regarding this, how is it normally done to run Spark jobs on-demand?

Comment: That's a good question. I would recommend [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40300222/best-practice-to-launch-spark-applications-via-web-application/40301106#40301106) as a starting point. In practice I cannot say if `spark-submit` thing is a big deal or not - the fine print is there, but I've seen it brought to light only once or twice.