# Create Spark context for each request in pyspark flask applicaiton

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, flask, pyspark

I'm new on apace spark,how we can create spark context for web based applicaiton.

The below i've used,

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
conf = SparkConf().setAppName('Test App').setMaster('spark://localhost:7077')
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/find_possible_events', methods=['POST'])
def find_possible_events():
     sc=SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=conf)
     data=sc.parallelize([20,30,40,50])
     d=data.collect()
     sc.stop
     return d
```

The above works fine when we had single at same time, but if we had multiple request means got error.

> Exception in thread "dispatcher-event-loop-8"
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

when i took at the spark worker log, it says spark context is not avaliable.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Thanks for reply. so we wont close spark context ??

Comment: Without going into details embedding like this is not the way to go, and a good solution is to broad for SO format. I recommend starting with  [Best Practice to launch Spark Applications via Web Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40300222/8371915).