# How to deploy war file in spark-submit command (spark)

Tags: apache-spark

I am using
`spark-submit --class main.Main --master local[2] /user/sampledata/parser-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`
to run a java-spark code. Is it possible to run this code using war file instead of jar, since I am looking to deploy it on tomcat.

I tried war file but it gives class not found exception.

Comment: i have a web application now i need to implement hadoop and spark concepts in it and java code ..created a job that implements the function but have to integarte it with web application

Comment: Possible duplicate of [run spark as java web application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40030394/run-spark-as-java-web-application)